# jQuery - is there a way to lock screen to current orientation after loading the web page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, screen-orientation

I feel its a simple question and im thinking i cant find an answer because 1. I'm not good enough at finding things 2. Nobody has thought of it yet or 3. it just cant be done and im out of my mind!

either way some input would be nice. im building a web app that uses jquery ui's drag and drop feature, the problem lies when the user decides to go portrait instead of lanscape or viceversa.

My idea is to be able to load the page in whatever orientation the device is being viewed in, and then lock it to the current orientation. if there is a way to do this it would be a lot quicker than trying to re position draggable elements on orientation change, although at this stage of the game any solution would be a good one

Comment: *"The problem lies when the user decides to go portrait instead of landscape or vice versa."* So, what is the actual problem?

Comment: Sorry I didn't seem to explain myself properly. My draggable elements end up disappearing off the right hand side of the page when the user changes from portrait to landscape. The container that is set in the .draggable() doesn't do it's job when orientation is changed. I think I read somewhere that position gets set to absolute when dragging is initiated. would that be where my problem lies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the only way to lock the screen orientation on a device is by making an application wrapper for it and handling it through native code. There are no capabilities for the HTML/DOM to set this behaviour as of yet.

Answer (score 2):

To more concisely answer your question, no. Unfortunately, it isn't possible to lock a browser into a certain orientation. You just have to take steps to make sure that the user experience is good in either orientation and that it transitions nicely between them. There are lots of resources out there to help you learn to detect and handle orientation changes. I don't want to endorse any particular solution, but a quick Google search will give plenty of good results.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect orientation on page load using this

```
var portrait = false;
if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){
    portrait = true;
}
```

Then based on that bool value you can determine the the logic of your app, the css rules to load, etc. Example:

```
 if(portrait)
     $(".mainDev").addClass("port");
```

For CSS, you can create two sets of styles for each orientation.:

```
.mainDev.port .menu {width:300px}
.mainDev .menu {width:600px}
.....
```

Assuming you have a containing div for your app with a class "mainDev".

Answer (score 0):

The idea that them being `portrait` or `landscape` is actually **irrelevant**.  The height of the screen won't affect the layout because it will scroll with it.  The `width` of the screen will be your best identifier.

You need to use `@media` queries to determine screen orientation

### CSS

```
@media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 599px) { 
    ... CSS rules for portrait ...
}
@media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 960px) { 
    ... CSS rules for landscape ...
}
```

And I would suggest using percentages for elements ( `width: 25%` ) and auto heights ( `height: auto` ) on things that don't specifically need something defined.

Also utilize `box-sizing: border-box;` on your elements to ensure *borders, padding and margins* are accounted for when determining element sizes.

### [A List Apart: Responsive Web Design](http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design)

- *One of my favorite articles to explain this in detail (very enjoyable to read)*

### [Example page grid in ALA article](http://d.alistapart.com/responsive-web-design/ex/ex-site-flexible.html)

- *Re-size the browser width to witness the changes.*

Comment: I've been using media queries for a good while now but they don't seem to offer a solution to the problem I am having with jQuery ui draggable elements. Would it be something to do with the position being set to absolute by default of jQuery ui?

Comment: If the offset (`left` or `right` properties in this case) is set past the boundary of the screen then yes, this would cause it.  And I was unaware that it was a Javascript-based CSS setting, my apologies.  That will be a different situation that my answer probably won't help with.